# Why did I lose 100 reputation on GIS?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

Why did I lose 100 reputation on Jan 9th?

When others do the same with a disclaimer:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367645/spam-flag-declined-on-link-from-founder-cto-dozens-of-similar-posts

On the GIS site, I am this user: https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/43169/jeryl-cook

It says "There were no net reputation changes on this day" , but -100 was applied.

Answer (score 12):

I was not one of the three users (two moderators) who cast or processed flags on your answer.

However, as a moderator I can confirm that these actions happened, as you can see below:

1. Ordinary user cast a spam flag
2. Moderator 1 declined the spam flag
3. Moderator 2 cast a spam flag (which deleted your answer, and presumably led to the 100 point deduction)

[image]

I can also see that you were contacted by the GIS moderators on 10 Oct 2015 about excessive self-promotion.

---

In this instance the question asked was:

> how many (or which) zip codes map to more than one US state or US city?

Your answer appeared to be "here is how to use ***one*** zip code to find that particular zip code maps to two US states/cities".  It therefore appears to answer a different and far simpler question, and acts largely as an advertisement for your API. Even disclosing your affiliation does not appear to have convinced two users (one a moderator) that your answer was not overt self-promotion.

Comment: Well i was told in 2015 I should add a disclaimer(saying i work for company) when answering a question which I did in 2018. But alright.

Comment: Was not my intention on being a spammer sorry.  i found the email you wrote:  "In your case one line along the bottom of each answer you give that involves your products to says something like this would cover off on it as an issue:

"**Disclaimer**: I work for VanitySoft"
Regards,
PolyGeo